# How to execute cmd commands in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I am really new to NodeJS and playing around with some functions. I want to use some commands from cmd using Node. My attempt was this here:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
code = execSync('node -v');
console.log(code);
```

But instead of getting a one-liner, I am getting a whole ChildProcess object like this:

```
ChildProcess {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    close: [Function: exithandler],
    error: [Function: errorhandler]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,.....and so on
```

Can anyone guide me please? Why is that so and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `stdout` is sent to the parent process. You can set `options.stdio` if you want it to go elsewhere.

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const code = execSync('node -v', { stdio: 'inherit' });

console.log(code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use additional `.toString()`

```
execSync('node -v').toString()
```

The type returned by `'child_process'` is `Buffer`, you want a string.

Remember though, that all the commands executed are ended with the newline `\n` character.

Full code

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const code = execSync('node -v').toString;
console.log(code);
```

will give you something like

```
'v10.15.1\n'
```

depending on the node version you currently run.

Answer (score 0):

Executing stuff in Node just isn't that easy, but there is a module that can make it easier. Take a look at [shelljs.exec](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs):

```
const version = exec('node --version', {silent:true}).stdout;
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look on that later